# Improve accuracy of thermistor circuit

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, signal-integrity, thermistor, accuracy

I am using [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Amphenol-Advanced-Sensors/MC65F103A?qs=FM6NhYOeeBUq6E6Yxo6GxQ%3D%3D) thermistor to measure temperatures between room temp and 100C and I want to design the circuit in such a way that it reads as accurately as possible (ideally +/- 2 degrees). I'm using a voltage divider circuit and the signal will go to a 5V Arduino pro mini. I know that using a constant current source is a good way to improve accuracy, but I'm not sure exactly how to get a constant current source. Can the Arduino provide this or is it a separate component or circuit that I would have to build? Additionally, I'd appreciate any tips for choosing components, minimizing signal interference or ways of calculating the temperature from the resistance value, or even tips for laying out my PCB that would help improve the accuracy of the measurement.

(R7 is the thermistor in the circuit below)
[image: circuit where R7 is the thermistor]

Comment: Improve accuracy and Arduino probably means calibration + lookup table for measured value to temperature. Why R8 and C4?

Comment: Room temp to 100C is a huge range. You may be better off with an inherently wide dynamic range converter like using the thermistor as the R in an RC schmidt relaxation oscillator, that you count the frequency of with the Arduino. Current source won't necessarily help, just a voltage divider with the reference voltage will give you all the stability you need, certainly for +/- 2.

Comment: Another advice may be to use bridge circuit and differential ADC mode with internal amplifier in order to take maximum advantage of its resolution without need for ref. source, since such thermistors are highly non-linear, yet precise. You can simulate (even analytically) dependence of ADC count of temperature since R(T) is defined in datasheet and select the best variant.